# Are tags with a name made of just numbers still allowed?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

On Drupal Stack Exchange, we had tags like *5*, *6*, and *7* for the Drupal version. All in a sudden, since today it is not possible to edit questions with those tags, even as moderators, because they aren't allowed anymore.
We have those tags since the site was in beta phase, when Stack Exchange decided not to allow tags like *drupal-6* because users would have picked them just for the fact they contained *Drupal* and the question was about Drupal.

Are those number-only tags still allowed, or is Stack Exchange blocking them because a bug? Should we use a different tag schema for those tags, considering that `drupal-?\d+` tags are black-listed?

Comment: asking around about this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sorry about this; this was my bad. It was impacting an API. I verified that we didn't have pure numeric tags on *some number* of sites, but I obviously failed and didn't thoroughly check all of them, which is my error. I will find another approach for the problem that I was trying to fix. The code has already been reverted. Again, sorry.

Answer (score 17):

This should be fixed. I don't know why the change was made, so until we can figure that out Michael has rolled it back.

If we have to restore it, we'll try & post something ahead of time explaining why.